# In the following, should we use $\in$ or $\subset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We define set $S=\{ \{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\} \}$. We also define subsets $S_1=\{1\}$, $S_2=\{1,2\}$, and $S_3=\{1,2,3\}$. It can be seen that these are subsets of $S$.

Is it correct to write $S_2 \in S$ ? or it should be $S_2 \subset S$ ?

**Further clarification:**
I have a system in which $S$ represents the set of all possible subsets of active machines. Assume there are three machines, indexed as $1$, $2$ and $3$. $S_2=\{1,2\}$, for ex, means that machines $1$ and $2$ are active (at a given time).

Comment: No, these are _not_ subsets of $S$. Neither $1$, nor $1$ or $2$, nor $1$ or $2$ or $3$ are elements of $S$.

Comment: A subset $A\subset B$ has the property that every element of $A$ is an element of $B$. The set $S_1$, however contains $1$, but not {$1$} ; $S$ does not contain $1$, so $S_1$ is no subset. Similar for the other sets.

Comment: You have made a major edit to your post, but you have simply ignored @Henning's point that $S_1,S_2,$ and $S_3$ are not subsets of $S$. Don't you believe him?

Comment: I just wanted to put the question in its right context. You mean with the clarification I have added, the answer is not the same ? PS: I did not ignore his comment, but I am just trying to understand all the written answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, $S_2 \not \subset S$, however $S_2 \in S$.  Each example of $S_1, S_2, S_3$ are **elements of S**. Note that S has $3$ elements: $S_1, S_2, S_3$

If you have $S_4 = \{\{1\}, \{1,2, 3\}\}$, then $S_4 \subset S$, or $S_5 = \{\{1,2\}\}\subset S$

Comment: Could you please tell me if your answer still holds after the clarification I have added. Thank you.

Comment: @din Yes it does. $S_2 = \{1,2\} \in S$, $$\{S_2\} = \{\{1, 2\} \}\subset S$$

Answer (score 1):

An element of a set can be a set again. For example, the power set of $M$ is the set of all subsets of $M$.

In your case, $S_2\in S$ is correct.

Comment: An element of a set is ALWAYS a set in standard set theory.

Comment: @question If we have $M=${$1$}, then $1$ is considered to be a set ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

Comment: @question In ZFC, yes. Nevertheless, even if a mathematician believes that their work operates on the foundations of ZFC, which isn't always the case, they will still tend to distinguish between the fundamental objects of their studies and sets of those objects (and sets of sets of those objects, etc.) - the former *technically* being sets, but not conceptually considered as such.

Comment: @question: more importantly, there's no need to confuse OP while they are learning the basics :-)

Comment: To put it another way, saying that every object is a set in mathematics is kind of like saying that every object in a computer is a binary number.

Comment: @question: At the level the OP is studying at, it is much simpler to assume that numbers are urelements. Representing numbers as hereditary sets is technically useful _when you're studying axiomatic set theory for its own sake_, but irrelevant and distracting when you're just setting out to learn how sets are used in the usual everyday mathematical vernacular.

Comment: I concur with @Henning  At this level, it seems the OP is studying the distinction between set membership (being an element of), and set inclusion (being a subset of). The only helpul  sentence you posted was that $S_2\in S$.

Comment: But your above sentence "An element of a set can be a set again", may have the OP believing that that $S_2 \subset S$, too, which is not true.

Comment: Please consider the clarification I have added to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

They are actually elements of S.  {{1}} = {$S_1$} would be a subset of S.